MISO on SPI bus not showing traffic from 2 out of 3 devices
I'm designing a PCB with an ESP32-S3 and a few different SPI devices. Specifically these:

DM9051NP (ethernet)
FM25F16 (FRAM)
AD7794 (ADC)

The issue that I'm facing is that when I connect them all, the DM9051NP seems to pull the MISO line to GND. In other words, the MISO traffic from the FM25 and AD7794 gets lost. When I attach a logic analyzer to the SPI lines, I can just see MISO doing nothing.
From the datasheet of the DM9051NP it says on page 9:

"SPI_MISO O,PD" with "O, PD" standing for output, pull down.

Page 27 goes forth and says that

"SPI Bus Control Register (38H)" controls the drive/sink strength of
MISO (2 mA being the least).

So... if I read this correctly, the DM9051 will just sink the 100 µA current that the AD7794 will source on the MISO, which effectively means the MISO line will end up being dead to the ESP32.
My questions here are:

Do I interpret the datasheets and behavior correctly here? Or should I look for something else?
How can I fix this issue?


Usually SPI bus devices can share the bus as the MISO outputs are tristated when deselected so the selected device can drive the bus. The data sheet is not clear on this case. Can you communicate with the DM9051 fine?

@Justme Yes, the DM9051 works just fine. That's also what's confusing me. FYI I checked if there's not a broken trace on the PCB or something like that; but the physical connection is just fine, and the SCK/MOSI traffic on the LA are what I expect.

So are you using the chip selects correctly, and have you verified the bus is free or driven by the DM9051 when all chip selects are inactive? Do all chips use same voltage levels, i.e. 3.3V?

Yes. You know, I'm just going to desolder IC's... let's see if that's making a difference, because that should make the whole setup much easier...

Well color me surprised... this was a software issue. I cut the power to all the IC's and noticed that the problem was still there. So I made a minimum piece of code for the ADC and the issue just disappeared. I still don't know where the bug is, but at least I now know it's not in the hardware.
To make matters worse, the SPI FRAM module gives back '00' when reading memory, and ignores any write operations until you enable writes. Read gives 00 because nothing is written, and the status register is 0. So instead of not working, it looks like it's not working - but actually is.

Cutting power to chips surely brings new issues. Typical chip would have IO protection diodes and would try to suck power from the SPI bus if there are logic high levels.

Thanks for the heads up... In this case it worked, but I'll keep it in mind.

FWIW This was a software issue.
I cut the power to all the IC's and noticed that the problem was still there. So I made a minimum piece of code for the ADC and the issue magically disappeared.
To make matters worse, the SPI FRAM module gives back '00' when reading memory (because nothing is written yet), and ignores any write operations until you enable writes. In other words: read gives 00 because nothing is written, the status register is 0, and write returns 0 because it's write protected. So instead of not working, it looks like it's not working - but actually is. Ironically, this was an off-the-shelves example that I was running on the MCU. The datasheet explains the behavior.
